# Retrieving hidden input value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input in the manner below:

```
<div id="message">
    <input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden">
    <span>Message with submit button <input type=button id="confirm" value="Submit"></span>  
</div>
```

The hidden input is given a value after a jQuery POST. I need to retrieve the value that is set, and send it in another jQuery POST.

Interestingly, I get this:

```
<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden">34345</input>
```

after fetching the value from the server in the first jQuery post.

Just `$("#hiddeninput").val()` does not retrieve the value which I want to send.

What is the correct way to do it in my example?

EDIT: In JQuery, This is how I set the value to the hidden field:

```
$.post("post.php", function(data){


    if(data.length > 0){
    var resultObj =  eval(data)[0];
    if(resultObj.SomeNumber >= 0)
    {
        $("#hidden").html(resultObj.SomeNumber);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the value of the hidden field like this, then it should work

```
<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden" value="34345" />
```

Comment: I closed the input tag. Still, the tag is re-formatted to this `<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden">34345</input>` after I retrieve the value via a POST.

Comment: @Jon try changing this $("#hidden").html(resultObj.SomeNumber);
to $("#hidden").val(resultObj.SomeNumber);

Answer (score 2):

The hidden element

```
<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden">
```

does not have the value attribute. It should be like

```
<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden" value="someValue">
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#hiddeninput").html() would retrieve 34345 from the structure as you show although as stated above the value attribute should be used on a hidden field and then val() will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since `<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden">34345</input>` is not the "right" way to format the input tag,a s opposed to `<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden" value="34345"/>` you need to use `$("#hiddeninput").text()`

Comment: Hey, this works! But does anyone see a problem that I'm not using the "right" way to format the input tag?

Comment: Well it is malformated markup, so you should probably start doing it the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

try explicitly adding the value tag to the input elemeent before the post adds it i.e.

```
<input id="hiddeninput" type="hidden" value="">
```

If that doeesn't work have a look at this thread:
[jquery selector can't read from hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996644/jquery-selector-cant-read-from-hidden-field)