# how to get html struts styleClass with javascript/jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I need to get the value of the styleClass element in javascript. Page is in jsp with struts/html tag elements. jsp code is

```
<input type="hidden" class="filename" name="filename" value="<%= filename %>" />
                        <html:file property="testfile" styleClass="testfile"/>
```

and onclick of button I invoke the javascript

```
function fields() {
    var filename = jQuery('.filename');
    alert(filename);
    var testfile= jQuery('.testfile').val();
    alert(testfile);
    }
```

However in the firstcase(filename) I get [object object] returned and in second case I get "undefined". Can someone give some pointers on how to get the uploaded file name in jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a value from an input:

`var filename = $('.filename').val();`

or

`var filename = jQuery('.filename').val();` (same as above)

read more here -> [jquery selector can't read from hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996644/jquery-selector-cant-read-from-hidden-field)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var testfile= jQuery('.testfile').attr('value');
```

It may be that your browser is preventing access to the value attribute for security reasons. Try both options in different browsers - Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.